# Is there a LaTeX command that will log to the output/error console?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, latexmk

I have created a LaTeX `\todo{}` command which outputs todo notes in the margin:

```
\newcommand\todo[1]{\marginpar{#1}}
```

However, I'd really like to output a list of all my todo notes to the output console. I had written a trivial python script to parse .tex files to do so, but have since switched to using latexmk to handle recompilation. My script doesn't really handle using `\includeonly` either.

Can I write straight into the LaTeX console output from within latex?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes -- try `\typeout{message}`.

Answer (score 8):

You should definitely give the [todonote](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/)-package a try.
It writes all your todos into the TOC (if desired) and writes a `.tdo`-file with all the todos into the directory of the root file.

Comment: Thanks Habi, I didn't realize this package also created a todo list file! I might see if I can trivially switch to using it. However, I'm going to accept Etaoin's answer as it more directly answers the question.